# Help Me Writing a Simple Regular Expression

Tags: visual-studio, regex, replace

I have the following text:

```
txtAddressSup.Text
```

I want the `Sup` to be replaced by `Cus` while the whole text remains as is. I have many texts that are in this format:

```
xxxxxxxSup.xxxxx
```

Comment: If you do not provide more info, all solutions will replace EVERY occurrence of the "Sup" string by "Cus". As your sample text seems part of a program, perhaps that is not what you want

Comment: Actually, i want some sort of regexp that whenever there is the word
Sup in the source code, it should replaced by Cus. This regexp will run on an editing tool called Find and Replace which allows me to edit the block of large source code.

Comment: Are you doing this using the "Find and Replace" from Visual Studio?

Comment: it will be important to know what you are editing this code in, as the regex language in VS is different from 'normal' regex flavours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question but I guess you are doing this in Visual Studio. Visual Studio uses a strange brand of regular expressions that is incompatible with most other engines. Try this:

```
Find: {:i}Sup{\.:i}
Replace: \1Cus\2
```

Explanation:

```
{...} Tag expression (usually called a capturing group in other engines)
:i    Identifier
Sup   Literal string "Sup"
\.    Literal string "."
```

To get help with this either see [the description of the syntax for Visual Studio regular expressions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) or press the black triangle next to the input fields to get quick help.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need to use regex?  Won't a simple string replace work?

```
myString = myString.Replace("Sup.","Cus.");
```

Comment: I need the regexp to run it in find and replace option for editing large block of code.

Comment: in the ide?  or can you just open the code file in a program, read the whole file in as a string, do the replace and then write the resultant string out as the new file...

Answer (score 1):

The regex to match those would be (common Regex syntax, not the one from Visual Studio):

```
\BSup(?=\.\w+)
```

Just replace the matches with `Cus`

Comment: I'm using this regexp in the Find and Replace option, which helps me make a massive editing.

Comment: In this case you should rather use the "Rename..." refactoring, because search-replace usually doesn't really work as expected (matching more than it should etc.).